# Dynamically allocate an array of unspecified size in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, input, char

I want to take an input in c and don't know the array size.
please suggest me the ways how to do this..

```
hello this is
a sample
string to test.
```

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148778/reading-strings-in-c

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` is one way:

```
char* const string = (char*)malloc(   NCharacters   ); // allocate it
...use string...
free(string); // free it
```

where `NCharacters` is the number of characters you need in that array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing the code yourself, the answer will involve `malloc()` and `realloc()`, and maybe `strdup()`.  You're going to need to read the strings (lines) into a large character array, then copy the strings (with `strdup()`) into a dynamically sized array of character pointers.

```
char line[4096];
char **strings = 0;
size_t num_strings = 0;
size_t max_strings = 0;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
{
    if (num_strings >= max_strings)
    {
        size_t new_number = 2 * (max_strings + 1);
        char **new_strings = realloc(strings, new_number * sizeof(char *));
        if (new_strings == 0)
            ...memory allocation failed...handle error...
        strings = new_strings;
        max_strings = new_number;
    }
    strings[num_strings++] = strdup(line);
}
```

After this loop, there's enough space for `max_strings`, but only `num_strings` are in use.  You could check that `strdup()` succeeded and handle a memory allocation error there too, or you can wait until you try accessing the values in the array to spot that trouble.  This code exploits the fact that `realloc()` allocates memory afresh when the 'old' pointer is null.  If you prefer to use `malloc()` for the initial allocation, you might use:

```
size_t num_strings = 0;
size_t max_strings = 2;
char **strings = malloc(max_strings * sizeof(char *));

if (strings == 0)
    ...handle out of memory condition...
```

If you don't have `strdup()` automatically, it is easy enough to write your own:

```
char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t length = strlen(str) + 1;
    char  *target = malloc(length);
    if (target != 0)
        memmove(target, str, length);
    return target;
}
```

If you are working on a system with support for POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), you can simply use that:

```
char   *buffer = 0;
size_t  buflen = 0;
ssize_t length;
while ((length = getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin)) != -1)  // Not EOF!
{
    …use string in buffer, which still has the newline…
}
free(buffer);  // Avoid leaks
```

Comment: memmove() ? Probably it will work, but I think you meant memcpy().

Comment: @wildplasser: No, I meant `memmove()`.  In this context, `memcpy()` would also work, but `memcpy()` does not always work and `memmove()` does always work, so I always use `memmove()` because it is utterly reliable, unlike `memcpy()`.

Comment: It may not harm, but it may confuse newbees. NTW: I don't like comaring `target` too a numerical constant zero, either. I would prefer: `if (target) memcpy(target, str, length);`

Comment: Each to their own; I don't like `if (target)`...

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the above answers. I have found out the exact answer that I wanted.  I hope it will help other people's questions also.

```
while ((ch == getchar()) != '$')
{
    scanf("%c", &ch);
}
```

Comment: There are so many problems with this fragment it is scary.  You compare the result of `getchar()` with `ch`, instead of assigning.  The result of the comparison will be 0 or 1, neither of which is the same as `'$'` in any standard code set, so the loop continues forever.  If `ch` is of type `char`, the `scanf()` reads another character (no checking); if `ch` is of type `int` (as it should be for receiving the result of `getchar()`), then the call to `scanf()`  is passing the wrong pointer type (though you might not spot the problem on little-endian machines).  All of which adds up to trouble.